# Evaluating the following definite integral calculus

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given the following definite integral

$$\int_0^4 \left[\left(1/2x^2 - 2x +8\right)-\left(1/4x^2+x\right)\right]\;\mathrm dx$$
I have done in the following process.

$$\int_0^4 \left[\left(1/2x^2 - 2x +8\right)-\left(1/4x^2+x\right)\right]\;\mathrm dx$$
$$\implies \int_0^4 [1/4x^2 -3x+8)]\;\mathrm dx\\ \implies {{{{1\over 4}x^3}\over 3} - {3x^2\over 2} + 8x}\\ \implies {{16\over 3} - 24 + 16} \\ \implies {2{2\over 3}}$$
I didn't get the right answer. Is there any mistake in the process I have done.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: $1/2x^2x$ at the very beginning. If this is correct, you seem to have lost something. Coud you check again ?

Comment: I have fixed this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three mistakes:

- a typo in your integral: you appear to mean $\dfrac12x^2 - 2x + 8 \dots$
- $\dfrac{16}{3}-24+16 = \dfrac{-8}{3}$, not $\dfrac{8}{3}$.
- $8x$ with $x=4$ is $32$, not $24$.

Also, you can check simple integrals like this with wolfram alpha: [here's your problem in wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F2x%5E2+-2x+%2B8+-+%281%2F4x%5E2+%2B+x%29+dx,+x%3D0..4)